# How to translate Elastic Search query in Java by using the query builder?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to translate the following elastic search query in Java, using the query builder? Can someone give any ideas of it?

```
GET <index-name>/_search
{
  “size”: 1,
  “sort”: [
  {
    “Date”: {
    “order”: “desc”
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: This is what I have done so far:

`SearchRequest sq = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices(index);

SearchSourceBuilder builder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
builder.size(1);
builder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("Date").order(SortOrder.DESC));
searchRequest.source(ssr);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SortBuilder` to sort on fields. Below request will sort `Date` field in desc order

```
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.size(1).sort(new FieldSortBuilder("Date").order(SortOrder.DESC));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-index");
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: @Marshmallow19 please go through the below answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?